# Receiving undefined offset 1

Tags: php, facebook

When user Login with facebook then i try to fetch their picture from facebook and upload it to my own website server but I'm Receiving error undefined offset 1, i don't know why I'm getting this error here is the code

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?width=410&height=310"; //$fbid is the fbid of user //
$no = imd(); //  imd); is a function that generat random string //
$name = basename($url);
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
$name = $txt.time();
$jo = ".jpg";
$name = $no.$jo;

$upload = file_put_contents("profile/upload/$name",file_get_contents($url));

$pic = $name;
```

Comment: your $url is getting error. i think you sending wrong parameter.

Comment: the error is from `list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);` because the result of explode is an array with only a single element on it `array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "picture?width=410&height=310" }`

Comment: @Monty the parameter are totally correct as when someone visit https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?width=410&height=310 facebook redirects to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c25.0.459.320/p320x320/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg

Comment: @PrinceG how to correct this error?

Comment: @PrinceG then how to get name of image, I'm Confused

Comment: What is your expect value of `$name`?

Answer (score 0):

As I have said in my comment above, the error is from `list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);` because the result of explode is an array with only a single element on it `array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "picture?width=410&height=310" }`

You can simplify your code into this:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?width=410&height=310"; //$fbid is the fbid of user //
$no = imd(); //  imd); is a function that generat random string //
// $name = basename($url); // COMMENT THIS  since you have another assignment for this variable below
// list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name); // you didn't use $ext, and since we commented out the next line, $txt won't be used
// $name = $txt.time(); // COMMENT THIS  since you have another assignment for this variable below
$jo = ".jpg";
$name = $no.$jo;

$upload = file_put_contents("profile/upload/$name",file_get_contents($url));

$pic = $name;
```